# Observe customer account verification event in Magento

Tags: magento

Is there a way to catch the event when the customer verifies it's account? I need this feature to enable user's access to other integrated subsystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `confirmAction()` doesnt seem to fire any events in

> /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

You could do either

1. [Overriding Frontend Core Controllers](http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/) to create you own event using `Mage::dispatchEvent()` or add code directly to `confirmAction` in AccountController.php
2. Use @Pavel Novitsky answer but you may need to check that you are on the confirm account controller or check for the changing of email verification flag, because this event will trigger every time a customer information is change/updated

eg

```
public function myObserver(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{

   if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName() == '....account_confirm'){
      $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
      ....
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every model has standard load_before, load_after, save_before, save_after, etc. events. Look at the Mage_Core_Model_Abstract to get the list of all predefined events.

For customers you can use customer_save_after event. In observer check original data vs new data:

```
public function myObserver(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
    $orig_active_flag = $custoner->getOrigData('is_active');
    $new_active_flag = $customer->getData('is_active');

    // do something here …

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even you can create your own event after customer vefication using below code.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('Yuor_Unique_Event_Name', array());
```

Now using this event you can do anything you want.